# Extending CollectionType with optional initialiser

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift-protocols

```
protocol Decodable {
    init?(data: [String: AnyObject])
}

struct A: Decodable {

    var data: [String: AnyObject]!

    init?(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.data = data
    }

}
```

This works when i want to create an object

```
let d = ["name":"Rahul"]
let a = A(data: d)
```

I am trying to achieve the following but it is giving errors at the compile time.

```
let dArray = [["name":"Rahul"],["name":"Rahul"],["name":"Rahul"]]
let aArray = [A](data: dArray)
```

The following code is giving me error 'nil is the only return value permitted in an initializer'.

```
public extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: Decodable {

    init?(data: [[String: AnyObject]]) {
        var elements: [Generator.Element] = []

        for d in data {
            let element = Generator.Element(data: d)
            if let element = element {
                element.append(element)
            }
        }

        return elements

    }

}
```

=================================
Answer : -

```
public extension Array where Element: Decodable {

    init?(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
        var elements: [Element] = []
        for d in data {
            let element = Element(data: d)
            if let element = element {
                element.append(element)
            }
        }
        self = elements
    }

}
```

This will allow you to initialise using the following code

```
let dArray = [["name":"Rahul"],["name":"Rahul"],["name":"Rahul"]]
let aArray = [A](data: dArray)
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: i added more information. I want to achieve let aArray = [A](data: dArray) by extending collection type.

Comment: @RahulKatariya In Swift, initializers do not have return value. This differs from Obj-C. In the case of failable initializers, you use `return nil` to indicate the point where initialization failure could be triggered. Also, you don't use `return` keyword to indicate initialization success. So compiler is complaining about your `return elements` statement, because you can't return anything except nil ...

Comment: @RahulKatariya: what do you want to do? And what this code should to `let a = A(data: d)`?

Comment: Thanks Whirlwind. My bad. So i have to extend Array then to have an init method.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because `CollectionType` is a protocol, which cannot be initialised. 
Have you tried to create a helper class method to return you the collection, e.g.

```
func collectionWithData(data: [[String: AnyObject]]) -> [Generator.Element] {
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. The helper method works fine but looking for a way so that i do it with initialisation.

Comment: Oliver, protocol cannot be initialised, but init? still can be defined by protocol extension. OP received the error, because init? must return (if) only nil value.

Answer (score 0):

let's define a protocol

```
protocol P {
    init?(b: Bool)
}
```

as mentioned by Oliver, protocol cannot be initialized, but we still are able to define init in protocol extension

```
extension P {
    init?(b: Bool) {
        print("init defined in extension")
        if b == false { return nil }
        self.init(b: b)
    }
}
```

see, that you cannot return anything from init but nil (if initialization failed)

let's define a class which conforms to our protocol

```
class C: P {
    var b: Bool
    required init(b: Bool) {
        self.b = b
    }
}
```

and see what happens in next snippet

```
let c1: C? = C(b: false)
let c2 = C(b: false)
dump(c1)
dump(c2)
/*
init defined in extension
- nil
▿ C #0
  - b: false
*/
```

the same expression `C(b: false)` give us two different results :-). So, be careful if you define init and init? via protocol extension. If you try to define init and init? with the same parameters without protocol extension, the compiler will complain.

Comment: Thanks I wanted to have init in Array of Protocol Extension.

Comment: @RahulKatariya Array is struct, not a protocol. so, (as you did) you can define init? in type extension. Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality. You can use protocol extensions to provide a default implementation to any method or property requirement of that protocol. If a conforming type provides its own implementation of a required method or property, that implementation will be used instead of the one provided by the extension.